# servlet parameter ORM

Tags: java, servlets, orm

Have any framework like JPA make servlet request parameter auto mapping to object?

ex :

```
class Object1 {
     String name;
     int count;
     Set<Object2> oset;
}

class Object2 {
     String name;
     int num;
}

Object1 o = Xframework.doBind(request, Object1.class);
```

Comment: Why would you want to do that? What do you want to achieve?

Comment: make my job more <s>lazy</s> easy...XD